# How to invoke a function after sshing to another machine in bash scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh

```
function test1 {
    ssh -i identity file USER@SERVER1 << EOF
    sudo su
    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
    some_other_commands
    exit
EOF
}

function test2 {
    ssh -i identity file USER@SERVER2 << EOF
    sudo su
    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
    some_commands
    exit
EOF
}

function common {

    sudo su
    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
}
```

I would like to avoid duplications on the scripts by invoking `common` in `test1` and `test2`. Ideally I want this

```
function test2 {
    ssh -i identity file USER@SERVER2 << EOF
    common
    some_commands
    exit
EOF
}
```

Right now it can not be invoked since it does the ssh first and `common` is not acccessable anymore from SERVER2.

What is the best way to solve this? Can someone guide me?

Comment: can't you put `common` as script file on the server ?

Comment: yes this is one way that could be done

Answer (score 0):

You could try executing what you need by redirecting `cat yourscript` to ssh. If you want the same script to be executed differently on each server, use `if` condition. For example, you have the next script:

```
$ cat sshcommands.sh 
#!/bin/bash

main () {
  if [ $(hostname) = 'pc' ]; then
    test1 
    echo "It claims to be PC......................."
  fi

  if [ $(hostname) = 'ubuntu' ]; then
    test2
    echo "It claims to be UBUNTU"
  fi
}

test1 () {
    echo "with common:"
    common
    hostname
    echo "This is pc"
}

test2 () {
    echo "without common"
    hostname
    echo "This is ubuntu"
}

common () {
    echo "Common start *******************"
    ls /
    lshw -C network
    echo "Common end   ********************"
}

main
```

You could pass it to your ssh server by command:

```
cat ./sshcommands.sh | ssh user@your_server_IP
```

How to work with `sudo` in this case you could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty). Look at `sshpass` solutions like this:

> ```
> $ apt-get install sshpass
> $ sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@server
> ```